# Trouble writing bash sed command - regex match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, macos, sed

I have a file full of garbage collection information that is irregular, some lines have extra information that I want to initially remove so I can then process the the file as a whole.

Unfortunately the line has quite a few special characters and I am struggling with a sed command that manages to match the bit I want to remove...

The line includes something along the lines of this:

```
[ParOldGen: 0K->0K(0K)] 0K->0K(0K), [Metaspace: 0K->0K(0K)], 0 secs]
```

The line has other information around the above string which I do want to keep, that includes `[]()` characters.

I want to match

```
[ParOldGen*secs]
```

and then remove it using sed

```
cat test.log | sed -e 's,<match>,,g' | ...
```

I went and checked on a regex checker, which came up with:

```
\[ParOldGen(?:(?!secs\])(?:.|\n))*secs\]
```

However, it doesn't match with sed -e and it errors when using sed -E

I can't use cut easily because there are too many other sections that have [ and ].

I was trying something like this:

```
cat test.log | while read line; do if [ "$line" == *"ParOldGen"* ];then cut -d ":" -f 1,9; else cut -d ":" -f 1,7; fi; done | tail
```

which would effectively work around it, but I have not been able to get a match on the ParOldGen, it always just executes the then portion.

My expected output is that I want to remove the ParOldGen line.

Is anyone able to help me with this one?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some more lines from your log file ?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: The string I want to match is always in the format I have given - There are other sections that have [ and ] so I can't use cut... it is in the middle of a line so there is no easy delimiter to use. I have thought about trying to use an if statement, but I want to do it in one line of code. I will put up the alternative command I was trying as well.

Comment: You want to remove the line completely?

Comment: Just the portion of the line that I have identified.

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear, for your test input, you want to get `: 0K->0K(0K)] 0K->0K(0K), [Metaspace: 0K->0K(0K)], 0`?

Comment: The line has other information around the above string which I do want to keep, that includes `[]()` characters.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of a line from the log file, and the expected output?

Comment: MacOS is very Posix-y. It is more line BSDs than Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the assumption that you want to remove the entire string starting with `[ParOldGen` and finishing with `secs]` from each line in your file. In that case, you can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\[ParOldGen.*secs\]\(.*\)$/\1\2/' test.log
```

The regexp grabs any characters before `[ParOldGen` into one capture group, and any characters after `secs]` into another. The entire line is then replaced by those two capture groups, effectively removing the characters from `[ParOldGen` to `secs]`. e.g. if test.log contains:

```
[Some other data (4) ][ParOldGen: 0K->0K(0K)] 0K->0K(0K), [Metaspace: 0K->0K(0K)], 0 secs] and then some more [possibly also with ()]
```

The output of `cat test.log | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\[ParOldGen.*secs\]\(.*\)$/\1\2/'` is

```
[Some other data (4) ] and then some more [possibly also with ()]
```